# Select specific number of Random Rows from Database after Joining the tables - Laravel 5.1

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Hi my database structure is as follows:

> Table: articles

```
id | category_id(fk) | title | description | image
```

> Table: categories

```
id | name
```

> Table: domain_category

```
id | domain_id(fk) | category_id(fk)
```

Now from above Tables. I need only **8 Random Rows** from table *articles* where **domain_id = $dynamic_domain_id**

What I've tried is as follows:

```
$randomArticles = Article::select("articles.*")
                        ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'articles.category_id')
                        ->join('domain_category', 'domain_category.category_id', 'categories.id')
                        ->where('domain_category.domain_id', $domain->lander_domain_id)
                        ->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->take(8)->get();
```

But I'm getting an error and not getting proper result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ...and what is the error you're getting?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'categories.id `` where `domain_category`.`domain_id` = ? order by RAND() asc lim' at line 1 (SQL: select `articles`.* from `articles` inner join `categories` on `categories`.`id` = `articles`.`category_id` left join `domain_category` on `domain_category`.`category_id` categories.id `` where `domain_category`.`domain_id` = 5 order by RAND() asc limit 5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only syntax error which jumps out at me is that you are missing an `'='` parameter in your second `join()` function call.  Try using this query instead:

```
$randomArticles = Article::select("articles.*")
                        ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'articles.category_id')
                        ->join('domain_category', 'domain_category.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                        ->where('domain_category.domain_id', $domain->lander_domain_id)
                        ->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->take(8)->get();
```

Comment: Great :) It worked and yes I just noticed that. Thank you friend for helping me.